# Login to box and print IP to a file in Python

Tags: python, ip, host

I am logging into a box and grep'ing a file content and printing to a file.  I can print the grep'ed text but I am not able to print the host name to the file.

```
import paramiko
k = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file("/Users/Documents/privatekey.pem")
c = paramiko.SSHClient()
c.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
print ("connecting")
c.connect( hostname = "10.224.58.214", username = "ec2-user", pkey = k )
print ("connected")
commands = [ "grep jdbc /usr/share/activemq/conf/activemq.xml" ]
for command in commands:
    #print ("Executing {0}".format( command ))
    stdin , stdout, stderr = c.exec_command(command)
    print (hostname,file=open("output.csv", "a"))
    print (stdout.read(),file=open("output.csv", "a"))
    #print("Errors")
    #print (stderr.read())
c.close()
```

The line `print (hostname,file=open("output.csv", "a"))` is erroring out saying hostname is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

`hostname` is not a defined variable, it's a named argument to `c.connect()` method. Define the missing variable in the beginning of your script. Below I used `h`:

```
import paramiko
k = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file("/Users/Documents/privatekey.pem")
c = paramiko.SSHClient()
c.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
print ("connecting")
h = "10.224.58.214"
c.connect( hostname = h, username = "ec2-user", pkey = k )
print ("connected")
commands = [ "grep jdbc /usr/share/activemq/conf/activemq.xml" ]
for command in commands:
    stdin , stdout, stderr = c.exec_command(command)
    print (h, file=open("output.csv", "a"))
    print (stdout.read(), file=open("output.csv", "a"))
c.close()
```

Comment: You are a saviour. Thanks a bunch. Its printing in a new line though , Can I print in the same line ?

Comment: @sorabhsarupria this might depend on your python version, check this quesiton: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-newline-or-space